# tensorboard cmd command doesn't respond in windows10

Tags: tensorflow, cmd, tensorboard

my project directory is:D:\PycharmProjects\MorvanL

my codes are:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import tensorflow as tf


def add_layer(inputs, in_size, out_size, activation_function=None):
    with tf.name_scope('layer'):
        with tf.name_scope('weights'):
            Weights = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([in_size, out_size]), name='W')
        with tf.name_scope('biases'):
            biases = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1, out_size]) + 0.1, name='b')
        with tf.name_scope('Wx_plus_b'):
            Wx_plus_b = tf.add(tf.matmul(inputs, Weights), biases)
        if activation_function is None:
            outputs = Wx_plus_b
        else:
            outputs = activation_function(Wx_plus_b, )
        return outputs


# define placeholder for inputs to network
with tf.name_scope('inputs'):
    xs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='x_input')
    ys = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1], name='y_input')

# add hidden layer
l1 = add_layer(xs, 1, 10, activation_function=tf.nn.relu)
# add output layer
prediction = add_layer(l1, 10, 1, activation_function=None)

# the error between prediciton and real data
with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(ys - prediction),reduction_indices=[1]))

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(loss)

sess = tf.Session()


writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("board/", sess.graph)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init)
```

after run the code, nothing wrong,

and the tensorboard file appear in the directory:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wYcd.png)

but when I run the command in cmd,nothing happend,why?
what should i do?:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBbL1.png)

Comment: tensorboard --logdir=D:\PycharmProjects\MorvanL\board                                                 when I run the up command in cmd,nothing happend,why? what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the official guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/summaries_and_tensorboard

> Once TensorBoard is running, navigate your web browser to localhost:6006 to view the TensorBoard.

So while your cmd code is running, open your browser and type `localhost:6006` in the address bar to see the TensorBoard.

Comment: wow! It works when I did following your advice! thank you very much!

Comment: If you find the answer helpful, please accept it by clicking the check button.

Comment: OK! I clicked it.o(∩_∩)o